# Muti thread join & get return values

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to do multiple heavy calculations using threads.
Then I need to do something with the results after making sure all threads have finished its job.

Here's the basic code:

```
    private class Runner implements Runnable {
      private String _result = "fail";

      public String get_results() {
        return _result;
      }

      public void run() {
        _result = "do complex calculation";
      }
   }

   public void test() {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        List<Runner> threadObjects = new ArrayList<Runner>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runner runner = new Runner();
            Thread t = new Thread(runner);
            t.start();
            threads.add(t);
            threadObjects.add(runner);                
        }

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

        for (Runner threadObject : threadObjects) {
            System.out.println(threadObject.get_results());
        }

   }
```

My question is, is above snippet a common or a good approach to get calculation value?
If not please suggest a better ones.
Also sometimes I got runner.get_results() reponse = "fail", it seems calculation does not processed at all.

Thanks

Comment: _Also sometimes I got runner.get_results() reponse = "fail"_ That should not be possible with the code you posted.

Comment: Depends a bit but look for `Future`s and `Executor`s. The common approach is that you rarely to never see the `Thread` class used directly.

Comment: You shouldn't get `="Fail"` from this code because you call `.join()` on each and every thread you create.

Comment: Using parallel arrays or parallel lists always seems like a bit of a code smell to me.  A single array or list of _tuples_ usually is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Adding to what @zapi said:  Threads are expensive to create.  If your `test()` method is going to be called more than once during the execution of the program, then you would benefit from using a _thread pool_ (e.g., `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`) instead of explicitly creating threads.  And, even if `test()` _is_ only called one time, it's still good practice to use a thread pool to perform finite tasks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The only thing I can suggest is that you take a look at your join call because it's based on your computer's timing so it could be a you thing. Try to get the same issue using sleep instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ExecutorService` such as the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`;

```
 ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(numOfThreads);
```

With `numOfThreads` being the number of threads you want sitting in the thread pool.

You can then use the `submit(Callable<T> task)` method provided by the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` class to execute the calculation.

You would then have a `Callable` implementation of your calculation and pass it to the `submit()` method in `ExecutorService` to execute the calculation;

```
class Calculation implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception { // The signature can be changed to return a different type (explained at the end)
        return "do complex calculation";
    }
}
```

As we can see from the method signature of the `submit(Callable<T> task)` method it returns a `Future`.

```
public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)
```

The `get()` method of the `Future` class will return the result upon successful completion. This would ensure that your calculation completed before reading it.

A further  note on the return type of the `call()` method;

Although this returns `Object` there is nothing stopping you changing the type of object it returns (this is known as [co-variant returns](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java))

For example the following is perfectly legal:

```
  @Override
  public String call() throws Exception {
        return "do complex calculation";
  }
```